# BottomNavigationView: Disable animation for adding/inflating menu runtime in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]I have a problem with BottomNavigationView. I have to inflate menu runtime and I have a problem with default animation. It looks like tabs slide from right. Do you know how to disable this animation/behavior.And when we inflate the menu it show not animation and apear without animation.
Please help me

bottomnavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menufile)

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.bottomNavView.inflateMenu(R.menu.mymenu);
TransitionManager.endTransitions((NavigationBarMenuView) binding.bottomNavView.getChildAt(0));
```

I am using this one. And its work fine.